# Bucket sorting string arrays and merging sorted buckets. Indexing Issue

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

Here is the code it's able to run (w/ output issues):

Another "issue" when I output the buckets sorted with a loop it outputs the "blank" array spaces as well(as expected). How could I tell the program to "skip" empty entries on output to console? (bit lost atm) been trying for hours...

Bucket sort loses items from original array

The program takes the random data in the program and sorts by last name into buckets then sorting the "buckets" with a bubble sorts.

Thank you to anyone in advance.

Current issue is located lines:

```
int y = 0;
for (int a = 0; a < (studentInfo.Length - 1); a++)
{ //no idea...Errors at a = 14... because the a + 1 index...so uh
if (String.Compare(studentInfo[a].studentLastName, studentInfo[a + 1].studentLastName) > 0)
    bucketOne[y] = studentInfo[a].studentLastName;
else
    bucketTwo[y] = studentInfo[a].studentLastName;
    y++;
}
```

Full/:

```
class Program
{
    struct StudentIDs
    {
        public int studentIDs;
        public string studentLastName;
        public string studentFirstName;
    }
    struct UserStudentIDs
    {
        public int UserstudentIDs;
        public string UserstudentLastName;
        public string UserstudentFirstName;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StudentIDs[] studentInfo = new StudentIDs[15];

        studentInfo[0].studentIDs = 331;
        studentInfo[0].studentLastName = "Thomas";
        studentInfo[0].studentFirstName = "Joe";

        studentInfo[1].studentIDs = 225;
        studentInfo[1].studentLastName = "Smith";
        studentInfo[1].studentFirstName = "Lisa";

        studentInfo[2].studentIDs = 002;
        studentInfo[2].studentLastName = "Jones";
        studentInfo[2].studentFirstName = "Tina";

        studentInfo[3].studentIDs = 333;
        studentInfo[3].studentLastName = "White";
        studentInfo[3].studentFirstName = "Bryan";

        studentInfo[4].studentIDs = 998;
        studentInfo[4].studentLastName = "Huff";
        studentInfo[4].studentFirstName = "John";

        studentInfo[5].studentIDs = 500;
        studentInfo[5].studentLastName = "Street";
        studentInfo[5].studentFirstName = "Zak";

        studentInfo[6].studentIDs = 772;
        studentInfo[6].studentLastName = "Abel";
        studentInfo[6].studentFirstName = "Karen";

        studentInfo[7].studentIDs = 222;
        studentInfo[7].studentLastName = "Streit";
        studentInfo[7].studentFirstName = "Susan";

        studentInfo[8].studentIDs = 332;
        studentInfo[8].studentLastName = "Thomas";
        studentInfo[8].studentFirstName = "Dan";

        studentInfo[9].studentIDs = 141;
        studentInfo[9].studentLastName = "Bryient";
        studentInfo[9].studentFirstName = "Bill";

        studentInfo[10].studentIDs = 880;
        studentInfo[10].studentLastName = "Forte";
        studentInfo[10].studentFirstName = "Mary";

        studentInfo[11].studentIDs = 900;
        studentInfo[11].studentLastName = "Ferguson";
        studentInfo[11].studentFirstName = "Fran";

        studentInfo[12].studentIDs = 220;
        studentInfo[12].studentLastName = "Worke";
        studentInfo[12].studentFirstName = "Elaine";

        studentInfo[13].studentIDs = 635;
        studentInfo[13].studentLastName = "Knapp";
        studentInfo[13].studentFirstName = "Justin";

        studentInfo[14].studentIDs = 445;
        studentInfo[14].studentLastName = "Dustin";
        studentInfo[14].studentFirstName = "Tom";

        WriteLine("              STUDENT INFO: (Unsorted Data) ");
        for (int i = 0; i < studentInfo.Length; i++)
        {
            WriteLine("Student ID #: {0} ------ Last Name: {1} -- First Name: {2} ",
                studentInfo[i].studentIDs, studentInfo[i].studentLastName, studentInfo[i].studentFirstName);
        }
        Write("\nPress Enter To Continue! ");
        ReadLine();
        string[] bucketOne = new string[15];
        string[] bucketTwo = new string[15];
        int y = 0;
        for (int a = 0; a < (studentInfo.Length - 1); a++)
        {//no idea...Errors at a = 14... because the a + 1 index...so uh
            if (String.Compare(studentInfo[a].studentLastName, studentInfo[a + 1].studentLastName) > 0)
                //if ((studentInfo[a].studentLastName.CompareTo(studentInfo[a + 1].studentLastName)) > 0)
                bucketOne[y] = studentInfo[a].studentLastName;
            else
                bucketTwo[y] = studentInfo[a].studentLastName;
            y++;
        }
        //sort two buckets now with bubble sorting counts swaps and compare
        int swap = 0,
            compare = 0;
        string tempString = " ";
        bool Swapping;
        do
        {
            Swapping = false;
            for (int index = 0; index < (studentInfo.Length - 1); index++)
            {
                compare++;
                if (string.Compare(bucketOne[index], bucketOne[index + 1]) < 0)
                {
                    tempString = bucketOne[index];
                    bucketOne[index] = bucketOne[index + 1];
                    bucketOne[index + 1] = tempString;
                    swap++;
                    Swapping = true;
                }
            }
        } while (Swapping == true);
        //Bubble Sort Two
        int swapTwo = 0,
            compareTwo = 0;
        string tempStringTwo = " ";
        bool SwappingTwo;
        do
        {
            SwappingTwo = false;
            for (int index = 0; index < (studentInfo.Length - 1); index++)
            {
                compareTwo++;
                if (string.Compare(bucketTwo[index], bucketTwo[index + 1]) < 0)
                {
                    tempStringTwo = bucketTwo[index];
                    bucketTwo[index] = bucketTwo[index + 1];
                    bucketTwo[index + 1] = tempStringTwo;
                    swapTwo++;
                    SwappingTwo = true;
                }
            }
        } while (SwappingTwo == true);
        WriteLine("Bucket One Sorted: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < bucketOne.Length; i++)
        {
            WriteLine("\nLast Names (Bucket One): {0}", bucketOne[i]);
        }
        Write("\nPress Enter To Continue! ");
        ReadLine();
        WriteLine("\nBucket Two Sorted: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < bucketTwo.Length; i++)
        {
            WriteLine("\nLast Names (Bucket Two): {0}", bucketTwo[i]);
        }
        Write("\nPress Enter To Continue! ");
        ReadLine();
        string[] FullBucket = bucketOne.Union(bucketTwo).ToArray(); // would remove any of the "same" name...
        Array.Reverse(FullBucket);
        foreach (var StudentLastName in FullBucket)
        {
            WriteLine(StudentLastName);
        }
        //string[] FullBucket = new string[15];
        //for (int i = 0; i < FullBucket.Length; i++)
        //{
        //    if (i >= bucketOne.Length) //- bucketOne.Length
        //        FullBucket[i] = bucketTwo[i];
        //    else
        //        FullBucket[i] = bucketOne[i];
        //}
        //string[] FullBucket = bucketOne.Concat(bucketTwo).ToArray();
        //string[] FullBucket = new string[15];
        //int numOne = 0, //i
        //    numTwo = 0, //j
        //    numThree = 0; //k
        //// Traverse both array
        //while (numOne < bucketOne.Length && numTwo < bucketTwo.Length)
        //{
        //    // Check if current element of first
        //    // array is smaller than current element
        //    // of second array. If yes, store first
        //    // array element and increment first array
        //    // index. Otherwise do same with second array
        //    if (string.Compare(bucketOne[numOne], bucketTwo[numTwo]) < 0)//???????????????
        //        FullBucket[numThree = numThree + numThree] = bucketOne[numOne++];
        //    else
        //        FullBucket[numThree++] = bucketTwo[numTwo++];
        //}
        //// Store remaining elements of first array
        //while (numOne < bucketOne.Length)
        //    FullBucket[numThree++] = bucketOne[numOne++];

        //// Store remaining elements of second array
        //while (numTwo < (bucketTwo.Length - 1))
        //    FullBucket[numThree++] = bucketTwo[numTwo++];
        //WriteLine("              \nSTUDENT INFO: (Sorted Data) ");
        //for (int i = 0; i < (FullBucket.Length - 1); i++) //Length -1 ?????
        //{
        //    WriteLine("Student ID #: {0} ------ Last Name: {1} -- First Name: {2} ",
        //        studentInfo[i].studentIDs, studentInfo[i].studentLastName, studentInfo[i].studentFirstName);
        //}
        //ReadLine();

        UserStudentIDs[] UserstudentInfo = new UserStudentIDs[20];
        int RecordIndex = 0;
        WriteLine("Enter Student ID #: ");
        UserstudentInfo[RecordIndex].UserstudentIDs = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());
        WriteLine("You May Enter Up To 20 Records: (Or 999 to Finish)");
        while (UserstudentInfo[RecordIndex].UserstudentIDs != 999)
        {
            WriteLine("Enter Student First Name: ");
            UserstudentInfo[RecordIndex].UserstudentFirstName = ReadLine();
            WriteLine("Enter Student Last Name: ");
            UserstudentInfo[RecordIndex].UserstudentLastName = ReadLine();
            RecordIndex++;
            WriteLine("Enter Student ID #: ");
            UserstudentInfo[RecordIndex].UserstudentIDs = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());
        }
        WriteLine("              USER STUDENT INFO: (Unsorted Data) ");
        for (int i = 0; i < RecordIndex; i++) //or user..info.length...etc
        {
            WriteLine("Student ID #: {0} ------ Last Name: {1} -- First Name: {2} ",
                UserstudentInfo[i].UserstudentIDs, UserstudentInfo[i].UserstudentLastName, UserstudentInfo[i].UserstudentFirstName);
        }
        Write("\nPress Enter To Continue! ");
        ReadLine();
        string[] bucketThree = new string[20];
        string[] bucketFour = new string[20];
        int L = 0;
        for (int a = 0; a < RecordIndex; a++) // or ? (studentInfo.Length - 1)
        {//no idea here again....
            if (String.Compare(UserstudentInfo[a].UserstudentLastName, UserstudentInfo[a + 1].UserstudentLastName) > 0)
                bucketThree[L] = UserstudentInfo[a].UserstudentLastName;
            else
                bucketFour[L] = UserstudentInfo[a].UserstudentLastName;
            L++;
        }
        int swapThree = 0,
            compareThree = 0;
        string tempStringThree = " ";
        bool SwappingThree;
        do
        {
            SwappingThree = false;//(studentInfo.Length - 1)
            for (int index = 0; index < RecordIndex; index++)
            {
                compareThree++;
                if (string.Compare(bucketThree[index], bucketThree[index + 1]) < 0)
                {
                    tempStringThree = bucketThree[index];
                    bucketThree[index] = bucketThree[index + 1];
                    bucketThree[index + 1] = tempStringThree;
                    swapThree++;
                    SwappingThree = true;
                }
            }
        } while (SwappingThree == true);
        int swapFour = 0,
            compareFour = 0;
        string tempStringFour = " ";
        bool SwappingFour;
        do
        {
            SwappingFour = false; //(studentInfo.Length - 1) or record index?
            for (int index = 0; index < RecordIndex; index++)
            {
                compareFour++;
                if (string.Compare(bucketFour[index], bucketFour[index + 1]) < 0)
                {
                    tempStringFour = bucketFour[index];
                    bucketFour[index] = bucketFour[index + 1];
                    bucketFour[index + 1] = tempStringFour;
                    swapFour++;
                    SwappingFour = true;
                }
            }
        } while (SwappingFour == true);

        WriteLine("Bucket Three Sorted: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < bucketThree.Length; i++)
        {
            WriteLine("\nLast Names (Bucket One): {0}", bucketThree[i]);
        }
        Write("\nPress Enter To Continue! ");
        ReadLine();
        WriteLine("\nBucket Four Sorted: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < bucketFour.Length; i++)
        {
            WriteLine("\nLast Names (Bucket Two): {0}", bucketFour[i]);
        }
        Write("\nPress Enter To Continue! ");
        ReadLine();
        string[] UserFullBucket = bucketThree.Union(bucketFour).ToArray();
        Array.Reverse(UserFullBucket);
        foreach (var UserStudentLastName in UserFullBucket)
        {
            WriteLine(UserStudentLastName);
        }
        ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: You have 15 items in your list. Your for loop goes from 0 to 14. But, for the last item in the list, you are trying to compare the `studentLastName` to the **next** item - `String.Compare(studentInfo[a].studentLastName, studentInfo[a + 1].studentLastName` - which does not exist. Hence the error.

Comment: Yes I know it errors there. How do i fix that could I just simply change the original array length(to 14)? or does something with the index [a + 1] need to change?

Comment: Well I’m not sure what you’re doing here but how about `if (a < (studentInfo.Length - 1))`?